# How to run a set of dependent groovy scripts without compilation?

Tags: groovy, initialization

I've got a set of groovy scripts (or should I say a groovy app) which has hierarchical java alike package structure and script names the same as class names. All of them are called from the main script (like a java class with main method). I need to call just that particular main script and get all other scripts executed in sequence when needed (or loaded and executed).

Practically, this can be acieved by having all scripts compiled and .class files obtained and put into classpath while running the main script, but that's quite redundant for a scripting (the idea is to have it working without compilation, even though groovy will do it somwhere behind the scene)

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Groovy can be used in a scripting environment quite easily - no compile step required.  Read this:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Running

You can write your usual main method etc. and call it like this,

```
groovy -cp foo/ foo/MyScript.groovy [arguments]
```

Or if you're in a *nix environment you can give it a shebang like so,

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
println("Hello world")
for (a in this.args) {
  println("Argument: " + a)
}
```

and run it using `./fileName` (provided you've marked it as executable)

Comment: Have you tried the first suggestion in a package structure? Lets say you have foo/MyScript.groovy containing main and depending on  foo/package/DependencyScript.groovy. Have you tried to groovy foo/MyScript.groovy it in such conditions?

Comment: Yea - Set the classpath like this, $ groovy -cp foo/ foo/MyScript.groovy or run the groovy executable in the same location MyScript.groovy exists.

Comment: My apologies. Your statement is true, it seems that my case is unusual. Thanx.